# Android Studio - Click item in listview, get a value from that position

Tags: java, android-studio, listview, hashmap

I am trying be able to click on a item in a listview and get the stopIdRoutes (String) value and pass it to another intent.

The values are put into a HashMap before being put into a list.

I have tried to use`listview.getItemAtPosition(position);` but this just throws an error: `java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to ie.*.student.*.dublinbuses.getStopId`.

How can I remedy this. I've tried some solutions on here, and they haven't helped with this situation.

I also created a getStopId class.

Also, the stopIdRoutes that is being sent to the next intent is the last stop id in the list.

My code is:

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StopIdResultsActivity.class);

            getStopId getstopid_fromclass = (getStopId)lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Log.i("Item", "Selected: " + getstopid_fromclass.getStopid());

            //Create the bundle
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            //Add your data to bundle
            bundle.putString("stopid", stopidRoutes);

            //Add the bundle to the intent
            i.putExtras(bundle);

            //Fire that second activity
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Hi what does your getStopId class looks like? and also class names normally start with a capital letter, e.g. "GetStopId". (:

Comment: I know, I left it uncapitalised, so I would delete it if it didn't work.

Comment: The class: 

`public class getStopId {

    private String stopid;

    public getStopId(String stopid) {
        this.stopid = stopid;
    }

    public String getStopid(){
        return stopid;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StopIdResultsActivity.class);

            GetStopId getstopid_fromclass = list[position];


            //Create the bundle
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            //Add your data to bundle
            bundle.putString("stopid", getstopid_fromclass.getStopid());

            //Add the bundle to the intent
            i.putExtras(bundle);

            //Fire that second activity
            startActivity(i);
        }

    })
```

and in other activity get it as:-

```
String stopID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("stopid");
```

Try using this, if still error appears, let me know the error

Comment: If error still appears, let me know the error. If issue resolves, accept and upvote the answer

Comment: The list is incorrect, I tried putting in the (possible) correct list name, resultList, but the symbol can't be resolved. This is possibly because it's a HashMap?

Comment: can u specify the list type u are passing in this listview adapter

Comment: Even if u r passing a hashmap, u can get key value pair at that position and fetch value from that key value pair

Comment: `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> resultList;`

Comment: `resultList.get(position).entrySet().getValue()` try this then

Comment: It's initialised as `resultList = new ArrayList<>();` Would that cause the error?

Comment: Yes, it must be `resultList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();`

Comment: `resultList.get(position).getValue()` try using this directly

Comment: It wouldn't allow it on the same line for some reason. so I separatesd it.

Comment: `HashMap<String, String> resultList_returned = resultList.get(position);`

`String stopid = resultList_returned.get("stopidRoutes");`

Comment: Thank you for your help.